# Windows To Go - Reduce shutdown timer when removing memory stick

Tags: windows, windows-8

Is it possible to reduce the amount of time it takes before [Windows To Go](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/devices/windowstogo.aspx) shuts down after removing the memory stick that it runs from? Currently it takes 60 seconds after the memory stick is removed before the system shuts down, but I would like to decrease this time.

Comment: Are you simply unplugging the USB stick before shutting down "Windows to Go"? Per MS: "You should never remove your Windows To Go drive when your workspace is running. The computer freeze is a safety measure to help mitigate the risk of accidental removal. Removing the Windows To Go drive without shutting down the Windows To Go workspace could result in corruption of the Windows To Go drive."

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. I know it's not the proper way to shut down the machine but I don't need a clean shutdown. :)

Comment: @user1049697 Yes, you need a clean shutdown.

Comment: @WesleyDavid A clean shutdown is of course vastly preferred and the best solution, but it is not the one I need.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very localized, non-standard, and unprofessional use of technology for an extremely unlikely edge case. It is trying to solve problems caused by using something in a way that it is not designed to handle

Comment: This is a site for **professionals** and you have asked an apparently unprofessional question. You really should clarify the professional use case for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Pull the power cable instead.

Comment: That is not exactly the solution I'm looking for...

Comment: Why not? You may as well if you're not shutting down clean. It carries similar risk and is near instantaneous.

Comment: Alternatively, if your PSU has a rocker switch, it may be easier to just flip it to off. Or holding in the system's power button until it powers off as well.

Comment: Take this scenario for example: You have your computer running from a memory stick and the stick is connected to a lanyard on your neck. Someone steals your computer, the key is yanked out of the USB port, and the thief now has a minute to read whatever you had on the screen. THen I would much rather have it shut down as soon as the stick is removed.

Comment: Windows to Go is not for people that wear tinfoil hats. It's not meant to solve the problem that you're describing. Perhaps you should rig a self-destruct switch that's tied in to the lanyard as well so that your laptop becomes a bomb when stolen.

Comment: You honestly think someone's going to snatch your laptop while you are using it and spend the next minute reading what is on the screen instead of running off with it?  If you are that concerned get a laptop security lock/chain and handcuff the thing to your wrist.

Comment: It sort of depends on what you are reading and who your adversaries are. But my question is still if it is possible to do it or not, and I would like to have answers concerning that and not snarky comments.

Comment: The comments you are getting here are simply to illustrate that what you are wanting isn't a proper way of handling the issue or using the tech at your disposal.  You would have to reach out to the development team at MS that created "Windows to Go" to possibly get an answer to this.  There's very little documentation on MSDN/Technet regarding this.

Comment: If you have the type of "adversary" that would break into your living area, steal your laptop, and then be fierce enough to spend that 1 minute reading your screen while holding you off physically instead of running, then you have bigger issues than how to shut windows down faster. Get some help, man.

Comment: @TheCleaner Thank you for providing the only real answer. I am well aware that yanking the USB stick out isn't the proper way to treat Windows To Go, but for certain scenarios it could be useful to decrease the shutdown time.

Comment: Honestly, the best I can even come up with is if you can find a way to program a "If USB stick removed then "hold power button for 5 seconds" to force the power off in 5 seconds.